# Shared code in umbrella app

Tags: elixir

I have the following directory structure for my umbrella app :

```
umbrella_app/
    _build/
    apps/
      client/
         config/
         lib/
           client.ex
         test/
       server/
         ...
    config/
```

Is there a way I can write code somewhere inside `umbrella_app` that will be accessible from both my `client` and `server` without creating another child app ?

Such as :

```
# umbrella_app/apps/client/lib/client.ex

defmodule UmbrellaApp.Client do
  UmbrellaApp.some_function()
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Create another app within the umbrella.  Assuming you named the app `shared`, then you would add it to your other apps mix.exs dependencies:

```
defp deps do
  [
    ...
    {:shared, in_umbrella: true},
    ...
  ]
end
```

Now you can call the code as though it were within the same app `Shared.do_something` for example.